# Toilet water running when full.

Tags: leak, toilet, valve

[image]

Our water bill tripled last month. For the past year or so, two of our toilets make a leaking sound and a hissing sound. We had a friends plumber come and fix it and it seems to have only made the situation worse. The picture (screenshot is the video) shows what it’s now doing. Even though the toilet is full, every minute or two, it makes noise like water is running. What’s happening?

Comment: Sounds like the flapper valve is leaking and may need replacement.

Comment: Seconding the flapper idea. This is exactly what's happened to me.

Comment: Replace the flapper first and see if that fixes it. These Flowmaster valves are designed to alert the household that the flapper is leaking. After a flush the water is on full until shut-off. If the flapper has a slow leak the Flowmaster does not slowly let water into the tank to replace each increment of water leaking out. Rather the Flowmaster stays off until the level drops by a certain amount and then the Flowmaster turns on full.

Comment: @ Jim Stewart, "Fluidmaster"?

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, this can be one of a few things.

- Leaky flapper, which has already been suggested
- Pull chain is too tight allowing water to seep under the flapper
- pull chain too slack and can get caught under the flapper.
- Water level too high allow water to drop into the overflow

I'd replace both the ball cock and flapper, it'll run you about 15 bucks if you do it yourself. It's very easy.